# Python 3 - Find at least 2 numbers in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, numbers, digits

I need to get a password created by the user in a program. The password should be 6~10 characters long and contain **at least 2 numbers**.

I'm okay to deal with the length but I have no idea on how am I going to make sure there are 2 numbers in the string.  I've tried to use `isdigit` but it only tells me if there are any numbers in the string.

How can I verify that there are at least 2 digits in my string?

Answer (score 3):

This is one way finding the number of digits in a string:

```
>>> pw = 'fgfg57gfgf7'
>>> sum(1 for x in pw if x.isdigit())
3
```

### Explanation

This:

```
(1 for x in pw if x.isdigit())
```

is a generator expression. Converting it to a list shows its content:

```
>>> list((1 for x in pw if x.isdigit()))
[1, 1, 1]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
res = []
for x in pw:
    if x.isdigit():
        res.append(1)
```

Summing up the ones gives you the number of digits.

Since you don't need the list but only the sum of the number,
a generator expression is typically better. It avoids building the unneeded
list.

### Update

As @TigerhawkT3 suggest this also works:

```
>>> sum(x.isdigit() for x in pw)  
3
```

because it gives this results:

```
>>> list(x.isdigit() for x in pw)
[False, False, False, False, True, True, False, False, False, False, True]
```

`False` and `True` are of type `bool`, which inherits from `int`, meaning
you can treat `False`as `0` and `True` as a `1`.

Comment: You don't even need to replace them with `1`, since `str.isdigit()` returns a boolean and you can do arithmetic on those (e.g., `True + True` equals `2`).

Answer (score 2):

This counts on the fact that `True` has a value of `1` and `False` has a value of `0`.

```
if sum(map(str.isdigit, password)) >= 2:
```

Here's another way to spell the same idea:

```
if sum(c.isdigit() for c in password) >= 2:
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below `re.search` command.

```
if re.search(r'\d.*?\d', password):
```

This will enter into the if condition only if the password contains atleast two digits.

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> password = 'foo1b2'
>>> if re.search(r'\d.*?\d', password):
        print("Two digits found")

Two digits found
>>> password = 'foo1bf'
>>> if re.search(r'\d.*?\d', password):
        print("Two digits found")


>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
password = "sd909sdj23"
counter=0
for ch in password:
    if(ch.isdigit()):
        counter+=1
if (counter<2):
    //Alarm the user here
```